# Prevent jQuery tooltip close on mouseleave for dynamically added class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In the following, I open a tooltip to the `p` element once the button is clicked, and close the tooltip if the button is clicked again.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var obj = null;

  $('input').click(function() {
    if (obj == null) {
      obj = $('p');
      obj.tooltip({
        items: 'p',
        content: 'Some help'
      });
      obj.tooltip("open");
    } else {
      obj.tooltip('disable');
      obj = null;
    }
  });

  $('.help').mouseenter(function(e) {
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
  });

  $('.help').mouseleave(function(e) {
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<input type='button' value='Click me' />

<p class='help'>
  Some text
</p>
```

What I trying to do now is the same thing except that I'm dynamically adding the class 'help' to the `p` element when the button is clicked.  Instead of the tooltip remaining open, it disappears on mouse over.  I observed the `mouseenter()/mouseleave()` handlers did not fire, so I replaced them with `on()`.  The events now fire, but the tooltip still closes.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var obj = null;

  $('input').click(function() {
    if (obj == null) {
      obj = $('p');
      obj.tooltip({
        items: 'p',
        content: 'Some help'
      });
      obj.tooltip("open");
      obj.addClass('help'); // Added statically in DOM in above snippet
    } else {
      obj.tooltip('disable');
      obj = null;
    }
  });

  $(document.body).on('mouseenter', '.help', function(e) {
    //console.log('on mouseenter');
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
  });

  $(document.body).on('mouseleave', '.help', function(e) {
    //console.log('on mouseleave');
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
  });

});
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  
<input type = 'button' value = 'Click me' />

<p>
Some text
</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tooltip seems to be hidden once the `mouseleave` event fires after moving away from the `Some text`. Unless you require the mouseleave function for something else, you can completely disable this event from the tooltip to achieve your desired result.

```
obj.tooltip("open");
obj.toggleClass("help"); // Toggle help class
obj.off("mouseleave"); // Remove the event from the tooltip
```

jsFiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/c1f0ft8j/